# How to distinguish between comments and notes in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Newer versions of Excel have a concept of a *comment* (a collaborative thing that can be threaded, and can assign tasks, etc.) and a *note* (what was called a comment back in the day, which is just a box with some text in it).

Is there a way, using openpyxl, to distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 1):

The two seem to present identically, other than in their actual text. Using this code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook("comment_example.xlsx")
sheet = wb["here be comments"]
comments = []
for col_letter in ["A", "B"]:
    comments.extend([c.comment for c in sheet[col_letter][0:]])

live_comments = [c for c in comments if c is not None]

print("Results:")
for c in live_comments:
    print("\n ", c, "[Threaded comment]" in c.content)
print("\n__getstate__: ", live_comments[0].__getstate__())
```

And [this spreadsheet](https://bvnarchitecture-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ben_doherty_bvn_com_au/EYDWvtWFjKlOimUct87xYhkBbGcX_e2qClKjhcsqMBKnSw?e=rZCMOr), you get this output:

```
Results:

  Comment: [Threaded comment]

Your version of Excel allows you to read this threaded comment; however, any edits to it will get removed if the file is opened in a newer version of Excel. Learn more: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=870924

Comment:
    I'm a fancy new comment by tc={B69A1084-5372-4FC9-8FC2-6A78EE8089AA} True

  Comment: Ben Doherty:
And I'm an OG note by Ben Doherty False

__getstate__:  {'content': "[Threaded comment]\n\nYour version of Excel allows you to read this threaded comment; however, any edits to it will get removed if the file is opened in a newer version of Excel. Learn more: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=870924\n\nComment:\n    I'm a fancy new comment", 'author': 'tc={B69A1084-5372-4FC9-8FC2-6A78EE8089AA}', 'height': 79, 'width': 144, '_parent': <Cell 'here be comments'.A1>}
```

So, it looks like Excel reports the new kind as a *Threaded comment* and the old kind gets no extra heading.

The annoying thing is that the difference isn't shown in any of the properties. Maybe that'll come one day.

I'd love to be proven wrong, and a better answer come up.

Comment: A bit of discussion of this here: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/2059